# How to pass gurobipy.Model variables through apply_async() in Python?

Tags: python, c, multiprocessing, gurobi

**Summary**
I am new to python parallel computing. I used Gurobi to build a DEA model and calculate the efficiency of each DMU (Decision Making Unit). In order to reduce the total calculation time, I divided the model into two steps to solve:

- Step1, defined k models
- Step2, optimized k models in parallel.

Step1 is correct and executable. But in Step2, when I pass the object parameter "gurobipy.Model" into my defined function `Solve()` via `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async()`, `TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects` appeared. And the function `Solve()` was not executed. How can I use the `apply_async` function to pass `gurobipy.Model` variables, or is there any other parallel method to pass `gurobipy.Model` variables?

**Details**
The following is the main program

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
from gurobipy import *
import gurobipy as gp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def runComputationgurobi(Root, FileName, ResultFileName, numInput, numOutput):
    '''
    input：root path, file name, number of input unit, number of output unit
    output：Excel file (including DMU number, best solution(efficiency), modeling time, solving time)
    '''
    #Data peprocessing
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{Root}/{FileName}", header=None)   #download data
    D = np.array(df)                                      #convert to ndarray
    transD = D.transpose()                                #transpose ndarray
    outputs = []                                          #empty list to store best solutions
    
    scale, S = transD.shape                               #scale : numInput+numOutput；S : total number of DMUs

    print("Build k models...")
    #Step1: Modeling
    '''
    call BuildGurobiModel(list of download data, number of input unit,number of output unit)
    return：k modeling times(list[float])、k Gurobi models(list[gurobipy.Model])
    '''
    build_time_house, model_house = BuildGurobiModels(transD, numInput, numOutput)

    print("Parallel computing k models...")
    #Step2: Parallel optimization model
    '''
    call Solve(kth Gurobi model)
    return：k best solutions(efficiency)(float)、k solving times(float)
    '''
    temp = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    print("Start parallel solve")
    start_time = time.time()
    for k in range(S):
        temp.append([k+1, build_time_house[k], pool.apply_async(Solve, args=(model_house[k], ))])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(f"{time.time() - start_time}s")

    for k, build_time, _return in temp:
        outputs.append([k, _return.get()[0], build_time, _return.get()[1]])  #_return.get()=(obj_efficiency, solve_time, )
    
    #Output Excel
    pd.DataFrame(np.array(outputs)).to_excel(f"{Root}/result_parallel_matrix_ChgRHS.xlsx", header=["DMU", "obj_efficiency", "build_time", "solve_time"], index=False)

if __name__=="__main__":
    rootPath = "C:/Users/MB516/Documents/source/Python Scripts/Parallel_processing"
    file_name = "test.csv"
    resultfile_name = "result.csv"

    numInput = 2
    numOutput = 3

    start_time = time.time()
    runComputationgurobi(rootPath, file_name, resultfile_name, numInput, numOutput)
    parallel_solveTime = time.time() - start_time

    print(f"solveTime:{parallel_solveTime}")
```

Build k models:

```
def BuildGurobiModels(transD, numInput, numOutput):
    '''
    input: list of download data(list), number of input unit(int),number of output unit(int)
    return: k modeling times(list[float]), k Gurobi models(list[gurobipy.Model])
    '''
    #Data peprocessing
    model_house = []
    build_time_house = []
    scale, S = transD.shape  #scale : numInput+numOutput；S : total number of DMUs

    for k in range(S):
        #Define model
        start_time = time.time()
        model = gp.Model(f"NaiveDEA{k+1}")
        model.setParam("OutputFlag", 0) # 0: disables solver output
        model.setParam("Method", 0)     # 0: primal simplex

        #Define variables
        #define lambda
        lambdaarray = model.addVars(S, lb = 0.0, ub = GRB.INFINITY, vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS)

        #define theta
        theta = model.addVar(lb = -GRB.INFINITY, ub = GRB.INFINITY, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="theta")
        model.update()

        #Set the objective
        model.setObjective(theta, GRB.MINIMIZE)

        #Define constraints
        #input constraint
        model.addConstrs((LinExpr(transD[i], lambdaarray.values()) <=transD[i, k]*theta for i in range(numInput)), name = "Input")
        model.update()

        #output constraint
        model.addConstrs((LinExpr(transD[j], lambdaarray.values()) >=transD[j, k] for j in range(numInput, scale)), name = "Output")
        model.update()

        #convexity constraint
        model.addConstr(quicksum(lambdaarray)==1, name="Convexity")
        model.update()

        build_time = time.time() - start_time   #modeling time

        model_house.append([model])
        build_time_house.append([build_time])

    return build_time_house, model_house
```

Solve kth model:

```
def Solve(model):
    '''
    input: kth Gurobi model(gurobipy.Model)
    return：k best solutions(efficiency)(float), k solving times(float)
    ''' 
    print("Start Solve!!!!!!")      
    #Solve
    start_time = time.time()
    model.optimize()
    solve_time = time.time() - start_time

    #print
    objvalue = model.getObjective()
    getobjv = objvalue.getValue()
```

When I run the code, the result appeared as following.

```
Build k models...
Parallel computing k models...
0.53267502784729s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/MB516/Documents/source/Python Scripts/Parallel_processing/ENGLIFH_TEST_PARALLEL.py", line 124, in <module>
    runComputationgurobi(rootPath, file_name, resultfile_name, numInput, numOutput)
  File "c:/Users/MB516/Documents/source/Python Scripts/Parallel_processing/ENGLIFH_TEST_PARALLEL.py", line 47, in runComputationgurobi
    outputs.append([k, _return.get()[0], build_time, _return.get()[1]])  #_return.get()=(obj_efficiency, solve_time, )
TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects
```

It did not execute the Solve function of step 2 because it did not print out "Start Solve!!!!!!" in the function `Solve()`. And the following program

```
for k, build_time, _return in temp:
        outputs.append([k, _return.get()[0], build_time, _return.get()[1]]) #_return.get()=(obj_efficiency, solve_time, )
```

has `TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects`. How can I solve this problem ? Thanks in advance for your answer !

**Environment**

- OS: Windows 10 (64 bit)
- Compiler: Visual Studio Code 1.49.1
- Python: 3.6.10
- Gurobi(solver): 9.0.3

Comment: Please try to narrow down the question. There seem to be several tools involved and it's not clear where the error originates.

Comment: Hi, @mattmilten,  I tried to narrow down the question in the Summary. The question is "How to use `apply_async` to pass `gurobipy.Model` objects" or "Which parallel operation method can input `gurobipy.Model` objects". In addition, I guess that `TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects` appeared because the function `Solve()` defined by myself is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can create and solve multiple models in parallel in Python:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import gurobipy as gp

def solve_model(input_data):
    with gp.Env() as env, gp.Model(env=env) as model:
        # define model
        model.optimize()
        # retrieve data from model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(solve_model, [input_data1, input_data2, input_data3]
```

For more information, please refer to the [full guide](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043111231-How-do-I-use-multiprocessing-in-Python-with-Gurobi-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this method. In addition, can I build a model only once and pass it multiple times in this way? According to my DEA model, what I want is to "build the model only once", then only need to modify the RHS of a certain constraint of the model, and do it k times (k is a positive integer).

Comment: No, you would need to create multiple copies of the model. A completely different approach might be [multi-scenario optimization](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/multiple_scenarios.html).

Comment: Hello, @mattmilten, after practice, I'm back to the original problem. Let me use the example [link](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/multiscenario_py.html) to illustrate. In the example, when the base model is defined, how do I modify each scenario in parallel (the example doesn't modify each scenario in parallel)? To modify them in parallel, I must use functions such as `pool.apply_async` and pass the `gurobipy.Model` variable. But this is back to the problem "pool.apply_async does not support passing gurobipy.Model variables".

Comment: Does any parallel operation function support the passing of `gurobipy.Model` variables?

Comment: The multi-scenario solution (just as a normal optimization) uses parallelization internally, so you should check whether you can even beat this using a (manual) outer parallelization.

Comment: OK. Does an (manual) outer parallelization means to use parallel computing functions like "mutiprocessing pool" to complete it?

Comment: Exactly. Gurobi already is parallelized internally and uses all available threads.